# "Не смотря на последствия" или "несмотря на последствия"?

Tags: пробелы

Нужно ли ставить пробел?

- [несмотря на последствия](https://www.google.ru/search?q=%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D1%8F+%D0%BD%D0%B0+%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%8F) — 100 тыс. результатов
- [не смотря на последствия](https://www.google.ru/search?q=%D0%BD%D0%B5+%D1%81%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D1%8F+%D0%BD%D0%B0+%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%8F) — 50 тыс. результатов

Разница всего в два раза. Значит, можно и так и так?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(1) **Предлог со значением уступки** (=хотя), слитное написание:

Сейчас он, несмотря на все мои усилия, находится под стражей.

**Но раньше он писался раздельно:**

Но ямщики, **не смотря** на дурную дорогу, везли его с быстротою ветра, и в 17-й день своего путешествия прибыл он утром в Красное Село, чрез которое шла тогдашняя большая дорога. [А. С. Пушкин. Арап Петра Великого (1828)]

(2) **Деепричастие, форма глагола "смотреть":**
 ― Да, хорошо! - так же тихо отвечала она, **не смотря** на меня. [И. С. Тургенев. Ася (1858)].

Вариант 2  встречается не часто, при этом в Нацкорпусе около 1000 примеров с раздельным написанием "не смотря на". В большинстве случаев они не соответствуют современным правилам. **Но вот когда были приняты эти правила - это вопрос.**

Answer (score 3):

В Вашем примере нужно слитное написание.

Несмотря (предл.) = не обращая внимание, невзирая.

Не смотря (деепричастие от глагола смотреть, "не" отрицательная частица).

**Ср.: Я быстро пошел прочь, не смотря по сторонам.
Выйти в море, невзирая на шторм. Невзирая на уговоры, бросить учиться.**

Comment: Я убрала "лишние" глаза. )))

Answer (score 3):

< *Можно и так и так?*

Нельзя. Разве что каждый третий из пишущих в интернете систематически попадает в такую ситуацию:

> Разбуженный поутру, он стыдливо отвернулся, не смотря на последствия
>   своего вчерашнего буйства - поломанную мебель и разбитую посуду.

Comment: Александр, вы хотите сказать, что "несмотря на последствия" - ошибка?

Comment: В этом примере - да, было бы ошибкой, а в обычных случаях - только слитно.

Comment: В каком примере - вашем?

Comment: Да, в моём примере.