# Запятая ставится или нет?

Tags: пунктуация, дополнение

**И(,) ведь даже несмотря на очень разряженную атмосферу, на Марсе случаются  сильные бури, которые выводят марсоходы из строя**.

Непонятно, как поставить запятую перед оборотом с «несмотря», как-то нужно обособить.

Если запятая не ставится, то почему?

Comment: Когда непонятно, как ставить, надо подумать — зачем ставить, а не почему не ставить.

Comment: Стоп, запятую надо после "ведь", а не до, "ведь" же не к обороту относится (переставить с "ведь" нельзя).

Comment: На комментарии надо реагировать, а у вас всегда игнор.

Answer (score 1):

`несмотря на` - это **НЕ** деепричастие. [Это производный предлог](https://rus.stackexchange.com/a/424995/203420). Причастие `разряженную` тоже никакого оборота не образует, соответствено никакого оборота тут нет.

Вывод:

> Запятая **НЕ** нужна, так как нет причин её ставить:
>  *И ведь даже несмотря на очень разряженную атмосферу, на Марсе случаются сильные бури, которые выводят марсоходы из строя*.

Comment: Обстоятельственные обороты. http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum/punctum-attach1 А чего одна осталась? Если не открываем, то и не закрываем.

Comment: Я знаю, что это в

Comment: Я знаю, что это предлог. Но обороты с этим предлогом всегда выделяются запятыми

Comment: @Максим не всегда. *Такие конструкции могут обособляться, однако пунктуационная трудность состоит в том, что их обособление **не всегда уместно, а иногда даже ошибочно.***

Comment: @oleedd а запятая после И что от чего отгораживает?

Comment: Так дело в том, что "ведь" к обороту не относится, оборот с "ведь" нельзя переставить: *И на Марсе случаются сильные бури, которые выводят марсоходы из строя, ведь даже несмотря на очень разряженную атмосферу.* После "ведь" даже немного пауза есть. А если бы и относилось, то нет правила, что сочинительный союз примыкает к оборотам. То есть отделяются всегда с двух сторон. Например, у Розенталя сказано, что деепричастный отделяется от союза. Даже логика там описана. Здесь она такая же.

Comment: @oleedd это уже совсем другое предложение.

Comment: Относится ли слово к обороту, определяется именно перестановкой оборота!

Comment: `ведь` - это союз. Да, он не относится к обороту, но он и не отгораживается от оборота запятой (в предложении из вопроса из вопроса). К тому же `И` в начале вообще убрать можно, смысл не изменится.

Comment: Здесь частица, а не союз (см. БТС). Чего не отгораживается? Нет такого правила. Обороты всегда с двух сторон отделяются, и без разницы, что перед (пусть даже союз или частица).

Comment: Ещё один человек, который плюёт на свои ответы. Да на этом сайте прямо эпидемия этого!

Comment: @oleedd https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/64206819#64206819

Comment: Ну так 7-10 заходили. Не сделал бы такой вывод только из одного случая, вы и раньше так поступали.